# Change the order of UI elements for custom policy sign-in screen

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I implemented a custom policy with the identity experience framework on Azure AD B2C and I now need to rearrange the items on the login screen.

[image: sign-in screenshot]

I thought about re-ordering this via JavaScript, but according to Microsoft's guidelines, this should not be done. (See [the docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/javascript-samples#guidelines-for-using-javascript)

Any idea how to re-order the local sign-in and the social sign-in sections so that the local sign-in appears first?

Comment: Maybe this can be done with CSS. The documentation you pointed to also states "Don't change the order or hierarchy of Azure AD B2C HTML elements. Use an Azure AD B2C policy to control the order of the UI elements." So policies should probably be the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant control this from within the policy. Although not recommended, the only option is to use CSS/JS to move these elements around.

Comment: Then what is being referred to in the documentation linked in the OP where it says "Use an Azure AD B2C policy to control the order of the UI elements"?

Comment: @Jas Suri - MSFT can you confirm this is still the case, and is this mentioned anywhere in the official MS docs?

Comment: @JasSuri-MSFT I would like to know as well, if you can confirm.

Comment: My answer still stands today.

Comment: To first comment : refers to the order of claims on a selfAsserted page.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need to dive into setting up a [Self-asserted technical profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/self-asserted-technical-profile) with [Display claims](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/self-asserted-technical-profile#display-claims).

> The display claims feature is currently in **preview**.
>
> The **DisplayClaims** element contains a list of claims to be presented on the screen for collecting data from the user. To prepopulate the values of display claims, use the input claims that were previously described. The element may also contain a default value.
>
> The order of the claims in **DisplayClaims** specifies the order in which Azure AD B2C renders the claims on the screen. To force the user to provide a value for a specific claim, set the **Required** attribute of the **DisplayClaim** element to `true`.